# How does work memory allocation for list?

Tags: python, list, memory, python-internals

I was experimenting a bit with python and I spotted a strange behavior about the memory size of the list object. I tried to find answer but I didn't.

I use **ipython** with **Python 2.7.11+.**

Here is the phenomenon I try to explain :

```
In [1]: list_A = ["hello", "world"]

In [2]: list_B = "hello world".split(" ")

In [3]: list_A == list_B
Out[3]: True

In [4]: from sys import getsizeof

In [6]: getsizeof(list_A)
Out[6]: 88

In [7]: getsizeof(list_B)
Out[7]: 168

In [8]: list_C = list(list_A)

In [9]: list_D = list(list_B)

In [10]: getsizeof(list_C)
Out[10]: 112

In [11]: getsizeof(list_D)
Out[11]: 112
```

So I understand that it easier for the C part to pre allocate more space than what it is necessary to avoid to many realloc.

**What I don't understand though is how the preallocated space does work ?**

It seems if you don't use the list() function to create your list it takes exactly the space needed. ("hello" and "world" are of size 42 + the normal list memory overhead)

If it is created by split it seems to preallocate way more.

If I call list() on them, it preallocates enough for a new element ?

**Does it mean also that for memory optimization, in case of use of split the best way to get back the preallocated memory is to recreate a list ?**

Thanks a lot in advance !

EDIT: I hoped some more in deep answer than the one linked. But it is fine I have found the Python source code.

Comment: Basically, if you are using Python you should not worry about memory allocation.

Comment: Okay I can't answer my question but here is some hints ! 
From the python source code  : 

/* Overallocate the initial list to reduce the number of reallocs for small split sizes.  Eg, "A A A A A A A A A A".split() (10 elements) has three resizes, to sizes 4, 8, then 16.  Most observed string splits are for human  text (roughly 11 words per line) and field delimited data (usually 1-10 fields).  For large strings the split algorithms are bandwidth limited
 so increasing the preallocation likely will not improve things.*/

#define MAX_PREALLOC 12

So 11 elements preallocated by split.

Comment: So calling list seems to be the best way to squeeze the too much memory used by split in this case.